# Why can't a massive particle decay to a lesser mass and a photon?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, kinematics, radiation

I want to calculate a process $M \to \gamma ~ m$ where m is a lesser mass state and M is a heavier state. Going through the Feynman diagram I get a matrix element ${\cal{M}}^2=2g^2(~(M-m)^2-2mM)$, but I don't think this can be correct. If $M\approx m$ then ${\cal{M}}^2<0$ which is of course bad. I've done this calculation myself twice, my advisor and I did it, I evaluated it with `CalcHep`, all give the same answer.

Now maybe I've missed a minus sign, but then you get a similar problem when $m=0$.What is going on here?

This is an unusual process that you don't see in the standard model, but I don't see anything wrong with it. There are deeper questions one could ask, like "how does this off diagonal coupling between $m,M$ arise?" but I can imagine some crazy model where you get this vertex and these questions should not matter for this discussion. I should never get ${\cal{M}}^2<0$.

Usual kinematic arguments such as an electron radiating off a photon don't apply due to the mass splitting between $M$ and $m$.

Is there something inherently wrong with this diagram? Is this some sort of cousin to renormalization, where I don't worry about infinity's but I worry about negative signs? ${\cal{M}}^2>0$ demands a certain mass splitting, but why on earth should this be?

Thanks in advance and I look forward to the discussion

Edit: including my calculation...
incoming M state has momenta p, outgoing m state has momenta k.

${\cal{M}}=\bar{u(k)}(-ig\gamma^{\mu})\epsilon_{\mu}u(p)$

squaring...

${\cal{M}}^2=\bar{u(k)}(-ig\gamma^{\mu})u(p)\bar{u(p)}(ig\gamma^{\nu})u(k)\epsilon_{\mu}\epsilon^*_{\nu}$

Averaging over initial spins,summing over final spins...

=$\frac{-g^2}{2}\rm{Trace}(\gamma_{\nu}({\not p}+M))\gamma^{\nu}({\not k}+m))$

=$\frac{g^2}{2}(8p\cdot k-16Mm)$

and

$p\cdot k=\frac{m^2+M^2}{2}$

So,

${\cal{M}}^2=2g^2((M-m)^2-2mM)$

Comment: If the result is right, I think it means your theory has violated unitarity. If so, maybe there's some way to see this by looking at the Lagrangian. Is the Lagrangian gauge invariant? It might also be useful to write the amplitude so we can see how the minus sign shows up in $\mathcal{M}^2$. Clearly you aren't calculating the mod squared of a complex number -- I'm guessing the minus sign somehow comes from the Minkowski metric, which seems to suggest a breakdown in unitarity and/or gauge invariance.

Comment: At this point, we are not too interested in where this term in the Lagrangian comes from. We know semi-similar models where we get off-diagonal interactions for Z bosons, but not of any where its a simple photon. But yes, I agree with you, I must not be squaring a complex number. I will edit my question to include my work for the decay and maybe you or someone else can see something that is going on.

Comment: Hm... I think it would be worth writing down the Lagrangian for this interaction to verify that it works (ie that you can actually get something gauge invariant and unitary). For two fermions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ with the same charge, unless I'm mistaken, the term $i \bar\psi_1 \not D \psi_2$ isn't real by itself. Probably you have to add the Hermitian conjugate as well. Maybe that other interaction adds another diagram to your calculation?  (btw to do a slash in mathjax on this site you can use "\ not" with no curly braces)

Comment: In the context of the standard model, the analogous point to the one I'm making is that the CKM matrix has to be unitary, you can't just make up an isolated interaction vertex and end up with a consistent result. I'm not sure if this will fix the issue or not, but I think it's definitely worth verifying that the interaction you're starting from can be derived from a consistent coupling, before you go too far down the rabbit hole.

Comment: Additionally, by analogy with the standard model, I would expect that you should be able to do a field redefinition between "mass eigenstates" (which would propagate without "decays" like the one you have) and "interaction eigenstates" (which would include oscillations between fermion states with different masses).

Comment: These are excellent points. I'm not sure how adding the hermitian conjugate would give a different answer. I still have the same incoming and outgoing states, so wouldn't I just get an identical copy of the diagram I'm calculating? So I'm guessing my $\cal{M}^2$ would just be multiplied by $2^2$ and I'd still have the same problem?

Comment: Our model is basically a milicharged, inelastic dark matter, if you're familiar. I can't find a vertex like this in the literature, so maybe there is a good reason why (or I just haven't found one yet) . Let me try to write a gauge invariant Lagrangian and reply back if I have any ideas. As for Unitarity, I'm not too sure how to think about this. How could I check if Unitarity is violated, or how could I ensure that it isn't?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes I think so. Trace of 4 gammas gives you a factor of 4 out front, dotting in the p, k momenta gives a factor of -2. i.e. Trace=4*(pk -4pk +pk) =-8pk

Comment: This question is currently very vague and needs clarification. Are you assuming that these particles are fermions? Are you assuming QED in four spacetime dimensions, or the full Standard Model, or what? What gauge symmetries are you assuming?

Comment: By being so vague, this question even appears counterfactual, since there are of course cases of (massive) particles decaying to exactly one particle of lesser mass and one photon, e.g.: [$K^{\ast}(892)$](https://pdglive.lbl.gov/Particle.action?init=0&node=M018&home=MXXX020), [$D^{\ast}(2007)$](https://pdglive.lbl.gov/Particle.action?init=0&node=M061&home=MXXX035), [N(1535)](https://pdglive.lbl.gov/Particle.action?init=0&node=B063&home=BXXX005). (Those examples all happen to be "parity = minus" states ...)

Comment: Also, and especially: [$\Sigma^0$](https://pdglive.lbl.gov/Particle.action?init=0&node=S021&home=BXXX025). (Which happens to be a state with "parity = plus".)

Comment: @user12262 Yes these processes happen, but not in pure QED, as I understand from the Ward Identity. Maybe I should have been more clear in the original question, but other commenters that I was discussing with seemed to understand what I was saying. See CosmasZachos rewording below for clear phrasing.

Comment: @tparker Fermions (hence the bar notation), beyond standard model , 4 dimensions, can build a model where $\chi$ gets coupled to the photon via some kinetic mixing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright I have a possible solution, and I would like to hear others weigh on it. Bottom line: this process via this vertex is not allowed.

With a vector coupling and a process $M\to m \gamma$, this violates the Ward Identity. i.e. $q_{\gamma}^{\mu} \cdot {\cal{M}}_{\mu}\not=0$ where $q_{\gamma}$ is the momentum of the outgoing photon and ${\cal{M}}_{\mu}$ is the Matrix-Element with $\epsilon^{\mu}$ removed. I think the only way for this process to satisfy the Ward Identity is for $q_{\gamma}=0$, but in this case the decay width goes to zero (and there is no photon).

Now you could look at something like a top quark decaying to a bottom quark via a massive $W^{\pm}$. So we could do the same thing with our $M$ and $m$ state but have a massive vector boson instead. In this case the polarization sum has an additional factor that I am guessing would remove the nonsense that we see, while also satisfying the Ward Identity. (I suppose this must be the case otherwise I don't think the top quark could decay like this).

I think a violation of the Ward Identity indicates that gauge invariance is violated, and cannot be saved. You can find a similar comment about this in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.09698) paper in the paragraph above Eq. 3.2. This paper goes on to produce a similar vertex, although with a tensor current instead, which I think satisfies the Ward Identity.

Does this make sense to people? I haven't been able to prove whether or not the Ward Identity is satisfied for the vector current; it looks like $q_{\gamma}^{\mu} \cdot {\cal{M}}_{\mu}>0$ for $q_{\gamma}^{\mu}>0$ but does someone know how to show this explicitly so I can finally sleep at night?

Is my interpretation of the Ward Identity accurate? It's a bit weird to me that I know gauge invariance is violated simply from this identity, and with no knowledge of other terms in my Lagrangian. For all I know, there could be other terms that save gauge invariance, no?

Comment: Well, yes, I suppose. Your vertex comes from $eA_\mu \bar\psi_M\gamma^\mu \psi_m$, but the current of two different "flavors" is not conserved, since it would require/generate  M-m symmetry; however, such  is broken, since, ipso facto, the masses are different. For M=m, the decay is prohibited kinematically: go to the rest frame of the decaying fermion.

Comment: For instance, there is no such vertex for $μ⟶ eγ$ for this very reason. The sought-for rarest SM decay *has* to go through a loop with a very different tensor structure...

Comment: @CosmasZachos I guess this makes sense, but I'm still surprised this kind of ridiculously simple process isn't allowed... now I'm wondering how one would treat atoms dropping energy levels by emitting a photon, in field theory. Surely there are plenty of cases where the initial and final states of the atom have spin $1/2$...

Comment: Makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @knzhou The process is allowed; it is this specific coupling which is disallowed. The effective lagrangian term for my second comment  decay is gauge invariant. But the OP’s coupling comes out of a gonzo covariant derivative of an m M cross kinetic term which has not been diagonalized away!

Comment: I am wondering if the right way to interpret this process is as part of a kind of flavor mixing between the light and heavy state, and the fact that you're considering the process as a "decay" from heavy to light without allowing the mixing back from light to heavy is what's causing your issue.

Comment: In other words, since the process arises from a non-diagonal kinetic matrix, I think the initial and final states you are using in computing this S-matrix element are not really good states to use, because they don't propagate freely. If you diagonalize the kinetic matrix, this interaction should go away.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ah, of course! The leading transitions that allow atoms to decay are dipole couplings; the corresponding QFT vertices have $F_{\mu\nu}$, not $A_\mu$ itself.

Answer (score 4):

The OP's answer is sound, but I will summarize the answer to his

> Is there something inherently wrong with this diagram?

to refocus the question.

The answer to this is **yes**, the vertex supporting it is not gauge invariant, and fits into the broad rubric of SM-compatible interactions:

- *There are no flavor-changing neutral (& photon) currents*!

Call the *M* state *μ* for the sake of simplicity and the *m* state *e*. There  may be, of course, a kinematically allowed hyper-rare, undetected, decay $\mu\to e\gamma$ in the SM,  but it is a loop-based term involving *W*s which mix flavors (including lepton flavors, hence neutrino such). Its effective interaction is proportional to
$$
F_{\mu\nu}~ \overline {\mu _R} \sigma^{\mu\nu}e_L +  \hbox{h.c.}
$$
which is gauge invariant, even though your pathological vertex
$$
\propto A_\mu ~\bar\mu \gamma^\mu e
$$
isn't: for the infinitesimal transform of it to vanish, you'd need, after an integration by parts, $-\Lambda \partial_\mu (\bar\mu \gamma^\mu e)$ to vanish.

This is the current whose charge $\int\!\!dx ~\bar\mu \gamma^ 0 e $ rotates  s to *e*s and vice versa. But you already all-but posited it is *not conserved*, since you chose s and *e*s to not be degenerate. You may check directly it is not conserved, violated by the mass difference. (If they were, the current would be conserved on-shell, also being the Noether current of the evident O(2) symmetry in that limit, but plain relativistic kinematics would stanch the amp.)

You can reverse-scope such a term cannot be there, since for vector currents it would have to come from the covariant completion of a kinetic term such as $\bar \mu   D\!\! / ~e$ which you can't have, as mentioned by @Andrew.

This is  because you already resolved any *μ*-e mixing when you unitarily diagonalized the mixing states to get eigen- kinetic and mass terms.  As an aside, this is exactly what happens in the *Z* neutral current sector, as the separate mass eigenstates are precisely the separate eigenstates coupling to the *Z*. This unitary cancellation fails for the charged currents precisely because the unitary diagonalization matrices of the upper and lower isocomponents need not be the same, so they do not cancel in unitary multiplication.